# Quotient rings as complements of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, quotient-group

I'm studying Ring Theory and I'm trying to develop an intuitive understanding of quotient rings. Am I justified in saying that $^{R}/_{I}$ is the collection of all subsets of $R$ whose union is the complement of $I$ in $R$?

Comment: Well, actually you can't since the union of all elements/sets/classes in $R/I$ is all of $R$, because $\overline 0=I$.

Comment: @rschwieb I didn't mention fields anywhere...

Comment: @A.Attia Sorry: I was thinking of Galois field theory. What's the connection?

Comment: @rschwieb Oh it's because I'm studying rings in a Galois Theory course. Sorry I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $R/I$ is the set of subsets of $R$ which are cosets of the group $(I,+)$ in $(R,+)$.

As such, they are pairwise disjoint and their union is all of $R$, not the complement of $I$ in $R$. One of them is, in fact, exactly $I$.

Comment: I see. What I don't understand is why $^{R}/_{I}$ is likened to taking the mod. Why is $^{R}/_{I}$ often called $R$mod$I$?

Comment: @A.Attia Because intuitively, it's the result of identifying two elements of $R$ which differ by an element of $I$.  So for example, if $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $I = \langle n \rangle = n \mathbb{Z}$, then the quotient $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ is exactly "the integers $\pmod{n}$".